# Помогите решить задачку по JS

Tags: javascript

Уперся в задачу, которую не могу решать. Хочется понять где я  и что не так делаю?

Условие задачи:

> Создайте функцию, которая возвращает значение, умноженное на 50 и увеличенное на 6. Если введенное значение является строкой, оно должно вернуть «Ошибка».

Вот что у меня получается:

````
   if ( x >= 0 || x <= 0 && Number === true) {
   var result = (x * 50) + 6
   return result
 }else 
   return result = 'Error' 
}
var test = -5
console.log(problem(test));```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function calc(num) {
  if (typeof num !== 'number') {
    throw new TypeError('Ожидалось число');
    return;
  }

  return num * 50 + 6;
}

console.log(calc(6))
console.log(calc(13))
console.log(calc(56.43))
console.log(calc('awda'))
console.log(calc(['item']))
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: @sko1208, пожалуйста) Если ответ решает проблему, пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку рядом с ним. Это отмечает вопрос как решеный и помечает ответ как решение.